# Changes is working in core path but not in local path

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, controllers, core, local

I changed some coupon code error message in core file.its working fine. 
but if i copy the file to local [below]  path , its not working for me.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php - working


app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php - not working
```

what else changes i need to do to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but copying files to `app/code/local` in order to override original core fiels **only works for blocks, models and helpers. It does not work for controllers.**

To override a controller you will have to create a module with the following in the `config.xml`:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>           
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Vendor_Module before="Mage_Checkout">Vendor_Module</Vendor_Module>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout> 
        </routers>
</frontend>
```

Then you'll have to create the following `controllers/CartController.php` file:

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php'

class Vendor_Module_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    // Add your custom code here
}
```

Comment: if it takes less time, can you please update the answer with complete steps of what and all needs to be done for this.

Comment: @BabyinMagento done

Comment: Its really disadvanatge for small devolopers for again creating module. i hope magento team will fix this soon in new versions, thanks a lot.

Comment: @BabyinMagento I highly doubt Magento team will apply such modifications to Magento 1 as Magento 2 is the priority now

Comment: thats true, is same logic in magento2 also regarding controllers ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento no totally different there's no code pool in Magento 2

Comment: oh, thats nice , you guys will be knowing be about magento 3 also :-)